# Unison is ignoring local config and overriding remote file permissions

Tags: unison

If I modify a local file, unison syncs that file but it removes all permissions on the destination server, leaving only the following permissions:

```
-rw-------
```

My local config contains the switches which should tell unison to ignore file permissions:

#### ~/.unison/my-server.prf

```
perms = 0
dontchmod = true
```

I start unison with the following command:

```
unison -ui text -repeat watch my-server
```

My local unison is version 2.48.4, remote is 2.48.3

Comment: I just reproduced this problem. I can't see why Unison would do this. I'll bet it's a bug. You should go [mark it as an issue on the project's GitHub page](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue). This resembles a very old bug that was already fixed. See the very end of the "*Changes since 2.27*" section of [the Unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#news).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, this issue went away. I'm not sure which of the following fixed it, but here's what I did:

- Deleted my local replica and the archive files under `~/.unison`
- Uninstalled then reinstalled unison locally (the same version, 2.48.4)
- Added `force = ssh://username@my-remote-server//home` to the config to mirror the remote server
- Once it had synced, I removed the `force` config option and started as usual

Now, for whatever reason and despite the version mismatch, the permissions are working fine.